# Organizing a task-based scientific computation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, combinatorics

I have a computational algebra task I need to code up. The problem is broken into well-defined individuals tasks that naturally form a tree - the task is combinatorial in nature, so there's a main task which requires a small number of sub-calculations to get its results. Those sub-calculations have sub-sub-calculations and so on. Each calculation only depends on the calculations below it in the tree (assuming the root node is the top). No data sharing needs to happen between branches. At lower levels the number of subtasks may be extremely large.

I had previously coded this up in a functional fashion, calling the functions as needed and storing everything in RAM. This was a terrible approach, but I was more concerned about the theory then.

I'm planning to rewrite the code in C++ for a variety of reasons. I have a few requirements:

- **Checkpointing:** The calculation takes a long time, so I need to be able to stop at any point and resume later.
- **Separate individual tasks as objects:** This helps me keep a good handle of where I am in the computations, and offers a clean way to do checkpointing via serialization.
- **Multi-threading:** The task is clearly embarrassingly parallel, so it'd be neat to exploit that. I'd probably want to use Boost threads for this.

I would like suggestions on how to actually implement such a system. Ways I've thought of doing it:

1. Implement tasks as a simple stack. When you hit a task that needs subcalculations done, it checks if it has all the subcalculations it requires. If not, it creates the subtasks and throws them onto the stack. If it does, then it calculates its result and pops itself from the stack.
2. Store the tasks as a tree and do something like a depth-first visitor pattern. This would create all the tasks at the start and then computation would just traverse the tree.

These don't seem quite right because of the problems of the lower levels requiring a vast number of subtasks. I could approach it in a iterator fashion at this level, I guess.

I feel like I'm over-thinking it and there's already a simple, well-established way to do something like this. Is there one?

---

Technical details in case they matter:

- The task tree has 5 levels.
- Branching factor of the tree is really small (say, between 2 and 5) for all levels except the lowest which is on the order of a few million.
- Each individual task would only need to store a result tens of bytes large. I don't mind using the disk as much as possible, so long as it doesn't kill performance.
- For debugging, I'd have to be able to recall/recalculate any individual task.
- All the calculations are discrete mathematics: calculations with integers, polynomials, and groups. No floating point at all.

Comment: Would it make any sense to make it "distributable"? I.e. design every calculation so that it could be performed "in place" by the main program, maybe in a thread, but also distributed on more nodes, a bit like SETI@home?

Comment: Not an answer, just a thought, but this seems reminiscent of what a build tool like "make" does when tracking dependencies between targets. The checkpointing in that case is handled automatically by the filesystem. Gnu make certainly has an option to use multiple threads. It might be worth looking into whether you could learn anything from how they do this.

Comment: I guess for the second-from-the-bottom task distributing it a la SETI@home makes sense (including the few million subtasks). All the other tasks take little time so it isn't worth it. I also don't expect to have access to much more than my own computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there's a main task which requires a small number of sub-calculations to get its results. Those sub-calculations have sub-sub-calculations and so on. Each calculation only depends on the calculations below it in the tree (assuming the root node is the top). No data sharing needs to happen between branches. At lower levels the number of subtasks may be extremely large... blah blah resuming, multi-threading, etc.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that you are exactly describing a map-reduce algorithm.

Just read what wikipedia says about map-reduce :

> "Map" step: The master node takes the input, partitions it up into smaller sub-problems, and distributes those to worker nodes. A worker node may do this again in turn, leading to a multi-level tree structure. The worker node processes that smaller problem, and passes the answer back to its master node.
>
> "Reduce" step: The master node then takes the answers to all the sub-problems and combines them in some way to get the output – the answer to the problem it was originally trying to solve.

Using an existing mapreduce framework could save you a huge amount of time.

I just google "map reduce C++" and I start to get results, notably one in boost http://www.craighenderson.co.uk/mapreduce/

Comment: Did you look at your link? "Note: This library is not part of the Boost Library. It has existed in the Boost repository for a number of years where I have developed the library to the point it is today. There was little interest from the Boost community in adopting MapReduce as an official library, so I have moved it from their Subversion repository to here on GitHub. I hope this will make the project more accessible."

Comment: @Offirmo: The general MapReduce framework definitely fits the bill (d'oh! Should have thought of that). The implementation specifics require a non-trivial amount of work though, depending on the framework. The library mentioned looks neat, but is light on documentation.

Comment: @David No, I didn't look at the link nor I endorse it. Now it's up to Brett to use google and pick a suitable map-reduce framework on the internet supermarket. Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

> These don't seem quite right because of the problems of the lower levels requiring a vast number of subtasks. I could approach it in a iterator fashion at this level, I guess.

You definitely do not want millions of CPU-bound threads. You want at most N CPU-bound threads, where N is the product of the number of CPUs and the number of cores per CPU on your machine. Exceed N by a little bit and you are slowing things down a bit. Exceed N by a lot and you are slowing things down a whole lot. The machine will spend almost all its time swapping threads in and out of context, spending very little time executing the threads themselves. Exceed N by a whole lot and you will most likely crash your machine (or hit some limit on threads). If you want to farm lots and lots (and lots and lots) of parallel tasks out at once, you either need to use multiple machines or use your graphics card.

Comment: Definitely. I was thinking there'd be a fixed number of concurrent threads (equal to the N you mentioned). Each would grab available tasks and churn away on it. After that was done, the thread would remain active, but process a new task. I wouldn't create/destroy threads per task because I shouldn't have to pay for the overhead.